# UPDATE Cassandra table using spark cassandra connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm facing an issue with spark cassandra connector on scala while updating a table in my keyspace

Here is my piece of code

```
val query = "UPDATE " + COLUMN_FAMILY_UNIQUE_TRAFFIC + DATA_SET_DEVICE +
                        " SET a= a + " + b + " WHERE x=" +
                        x + " AND y=" + y +
                        " AND z=" + x

println(query)

val KeySpace    = new CassandraSQLContext(sparkContext)
KeySpace.setKeyspace(KEYSPACE)

hourUniqueKeySpace.sql(query)
```

When I execute this code, I'm getting an error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``insert'' expected but identifier UPDATE found
```

Any idea why this is happening?
How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the result if you run the SQL statement that is generated by your code directly on Cassandra?

Comment: @kerkero : If I run it on cassandra, it will either update the row if the key is already present, or will create a new row for that key if the key is not present

Comment: Did you define the column which corresponds to "a" in your example as counter type?

Comment: If is defined, BTW... its not counter, its a set

Comment: Hi @SunilKumarBM, in an arguably biased view I'd recommend using phantom for a normal Cassandra application, the spark connector is specifically geared towards Spark applications, whereas phantom is meant to be the foundation of any Cassandra based API.

Answer (score 6):

The UPDATE of a table with [counter column](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html) is feasible via the spark-cassandra-connector. You will have to use DataFrames and [DataFrameWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter) method save with mode "append" (or [SaveMode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode).Append if you prefer). Check the code [DataFrameWriter.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L41).

For example, given a table:

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM name_counter ;

 name    | surname | count
---------+---------+-------
    John |   Smith |   100
   Zhang |     Wei |  1000
 Angelos |   Papas |    10
```

The code should look like this:

```
val updateRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(Row("John",    "Smith", 1L),
                                   Row("Zhang",   "Wei",   2L),
                                   Row("Angelos", "Papas", 3L)))

val tblStruct = new StructType(
    Array(StructField("name",    StringType, nullable = false),
          StructField("surname", StringType, nullable = false),
          StructField("count",   LongType,   nullable = false)))

val updateDf  = sqlContext.createDataFrame(updateRdd, tblStruct)

updateDf.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options(Map("keyspace" -> "test", "table" -> "name_counter"))
.mode("append")
.save()
```

After UPDATE:

```
 name    | surname | count
---------+---------+-------
    John |   Smith |   101
   Zhang |     Wei |  1002
 Angelos |   Papas |    13
```

The DataFrame conversion can be simpler by implicitly convert an [RDD to a DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds): `import sqlContext.implicits._` and using `.toDF()`.

Check the full code for this toy application:
https://github.com/kyrsideris/SparkUpdateCassandra/tree/master

Since versions are very important here, the above apply to Scala 2.11.7, Spark 1.5.1, spark-cassandra-connector 1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11, Cassandra 3.0.5.
DataFrameWriter is designated as `@Experimental` since `@since 1.4.0`.

Comment: how can i insert new record or delete using dataframe?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you cannot update natively through the SPARK connector. See the [documention](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md):

**"The default behavior of the Spark Cassandra Connector is to overwrite collections when inserted into a cassandra table. To override this behavior you can specify a custom mapper with instructions on how you would like the collection to be treated."**

So you'll want to actually INSERT a new record with an existing key.